# downloading android .apk as .zip in android issue

Tags: android

I have developed an application,but when my client tries to download the application from the url provided using Samsung GT19003,it is downloading as .zip file and on click of that it says could not open the file error.Whereas it downloads as .apk and  works good in our devices.Please help me as how can i resolve the issue.

Comment: How does the client loads the file?

Comment: Some android phones have problems downloading zip/apk files without apps such as https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hwkrbbt.downloadall&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5od2tyYmJ0LmRvd25sb2FkYWxsIl0. being installed. Maybe get your client to install this and retry

Comment: @WarrenFaith The client is downloading it using his mobile browser,but the .apk file is being saved as .zip file

Comment: @Tony The issue with the client is .apk file being saved as .zip and so couldnot install the app.The link you provided helps to download files,but what we need is the reason as why .apk is saved as .zip and am unable to even rename it using MyFiles Filemanager

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you have set the http `Content-Type` to `application/vnd.android.package-archive`

This let the chrome know that it is an application not a zip.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to add the below line in /etc/mime.types

```
application/vnd.android.package-archive     apk
```

And restart your apache.

This will force browsers to download files as "apk" and not append "zip" to it.

Comment: Not sure why, but doing this and thendownloading directly to Android, any apk I've downloaded already are still downloading as ZIP, new apks are downloading as APK though...  maybe some sort of caching on Android?  not sure, but I'd say this is the sys-admin's answer, where as other answers are from a user's point of view.

Answer (score 1):

In my case also the issue was same as @alireza-fattahi mentioned regarding the header.

Sharing this here because in our case the file was in **Azure Storage** and accessed by a **CDN** in case anyone has the same issue.

### Fix for Azure Sorage and CDN

By default the APK blob that was uploaded had content type of `application/zip` and the same content type reflected in the reposnse header causing the downloaded file to get a `.zip` extension on Android OS when download was finished.

I had to set a custom rule in the storage CDN to overwrite `content-type` header in the response to `application/vnd.android.package-archive`

> Remember to purge the CDN cache after you set the new rule

Read more about [Azure CDN rules engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine-actions).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Example :
// set your download apk path here

> $path= public_path(). "/upload/apk/Ninja11.apk";

```
//Set header here like this
$headers =  [
            'Content-Type'=>'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
            'Content-Disposition'=> 'attachment; filename="ninja-release.apk"',
        ];
```

> **return response()->file($path , $headers);**

This is Laravel framework code but in the same way, you can use in other frameworks. Simply you need to set the Content type

> Note : This is not Android side issues

Answer (score 0):

if its being downloaded as .zip

1. You or your client can use **File Expert** `application` to **unzip** this .**zip** file it must show .apk file in the unzip folder
2. give a direct apk link to your user either he/she use default browser to download or use some other like opera and if it is .apk file link then it must be downloaded as is.
3. you may be using some content site which zip file on particular download methods please ensure it for direct .apk link.

**EDIT 1:**

1. Last but not the least **.apk is just a zip file** so this is not an issue **just rename it(From .Zip to .apk)** if you could and i hope it will solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply.We are providing direct .apk link.It is getting downloaded and installed directly without issue in our phones.

Comment: use file expert ot unzip as suggested then

Comment: This is not a proper solution. Many users will not be so technical to know that they have to download file explorer then go there and rename to apk and then try to install. I am losing many customers because of this.